# How can I use a text file as a database in javascript? (Firefox addon)

Tags: javascript, database, text, firefox-addon, crud

I have a text file like this:

```
settings:value
data:integer:boolean
data:integer:boolean
data:integer:boolean
data:integer:boolean
...
```

I need CRUD operations over this text file using javascript.
**This file is in the same js file's directory.**

**EDIT** after some comments: 
This is for a **Firefox addon**. Maybe we can count with more privileges?

Comment: Are you talking client-side JS, with the file in the same directory on the server?

Comment: You can't. JavaScript can't edit external files, it can only read them.

Comment: client-side JS. No server side interaction

Comment: Where's the file, on the client machine then?  As mblase75 says, JS has no write capabilities.

Comment: You might want to investigate the HTML5 [web storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) facilities.  Only in newer browsers.

Comment: So that is? No write capabilities?

Comment: Where is the JavaScript running?  In a regular browser, an `.hta` browser, cscript, wscript?  On Windows?

Comment: This is for a Firefox addon. I edited the question....

Comment: So the text file is in the same directory as the js file.  Is that directory on the server or the client?  (Really, it doesn't matter where the js file is located - what does matter is where the text file is located)

Comment: @pointy `web storage` really interesting! But this text file is provided by another program in the client's machine (a desktop app). So it must be a text file. thanks!

Comment: @gilly3 is in the client-side. No server here. This is for a Firefox addon.

Comment: "This file is in the same js file's directory."  What does that mean?  Remove it or restate it in the question.

Comment: @fantius "This file is in the same js file's directory." means: the text file is in the same directory that the javascript file is". (Sorry, I am no English speaker)

Comment: If it is a firefox addon, you should tag it as such - quite a different question in that light.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)... but it will only work on Chrome :(

Other browsers will allow you to [read files using the HTML5 File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), but only Chrome will let you write.

Comment: It also only works on local client-side files, not remote ones.

Comment: @mblase75 - I think that's what he's asking for: the OP [commented above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300327/how-can-i-use-a-text-file-as-a-database-in-javascript/8300363#comment-10225670) says "client-side JS. No server side interaction"

Comment: Yes, It must be a text file (in the client-side -for a Firefox addon-) This addon interacts with a desktop app. The desktop app writes this file and the FF addon read each line and mark one by one as `executed`.

Comment: @NomikOS - There's an article on [MDN about File I/O which is tagged "extensions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO)... but I'm not sure if it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**
YES! It is possible read and write text files in a privileged ambient as it is inside a Firefox addon.
The best solution I have found is using: [Basic JavaScript File and Directory IO module](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Io.js) and here is a little tutorial about it: [File I/O with Firefox Add-ons](http://17of26.com/2009/07/file-io-with-firefox-addons/)